# Cordova builds ios but won't run

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cordova

I have been working with cordova & Android for a while now, everything works,

The thing is that I wanted to add IOS and run the project so I could check prepare for that wasn't working,

The thing is that it builds fine ( [log](http://pastebin.com/6NTi47rE) ) but when running I get:

```
Running command: /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios/cordova/run --emulator
Building project  : /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios/funcook.xcodeproj
    Configuration : Debug
    Platform      : emulator
Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = i386
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator9.1
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
    VALID_ARCHS = i386

Build settings from configuration file '/Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig':
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
    ENABLE_BITCODE = NO

=== BUILD TARGET CordovaLib OF PROJECT CordovaLib WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

=== BUILD TARGET funcook OF PROJECT funcook WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

PhaseScriptExecution Copy\ www\ directory build/funcook.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/funcook.build/Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh
    cd /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios/build/funcook.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/funcook.build/Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh

ProcessInfoPlistFile build/emulator/funcook.app/Info.plist funcook/funcook-Info.plist
    cd /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
    builtin-infoPlistUtility /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios/funcook/funcook-Info.plist -genpkginfo /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios/build/emulator/funcook.app/PkgInfo -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphonesimulator -additionalcontentfile /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios/build/funcook.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/funcook.build/MainViewController-PartialInfo.plist -o /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios/build/emulator/funcook.app/Info.plist

GenerateDSYMFile build/emulator/funcook.app.dSYM build/emulator/funcook.app/funcook
    cd /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios/build/emulator/funcook.app/funcook -o /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios/build/emulator/funcook.app.dSYM

Touch build/emulator/funcook.app
    cd /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
    /usr/bin/touch -c /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios/build/emulator/funcook.app

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-6 simulator
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159):
Invalid device state
ENOENT, no such file or directory '/var/root/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/759B7226-A331-436D-8189-310317E9BD87/system.log'
Error code 1 for command: ios-sim with args: launch,/Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios/build/emulator/funcook.app,--devicetypeid,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6,--stderr,/Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--stdout,/Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--exit
Error: /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```

I am working with the latest version of El Capitan, cordova and xcode,

What am I missing here?

PS: In the same project Android builds and runs...

-EDIT-

If I open from xcode I get:

[image]

-EDIT-

Now it runs with emulator from xcode, but still not from terminal `cordova run ios --emulator`

Comment: do you have more than one xcode version? try to open the xcode project (it's in platforms/ios, double click on the .xcodeproj) if you updated it recently it might be waiting for you to accept terms

Comment: I'm on it, I'm running through xcode instead of terminal (loading..)

Comment: It didn't seem to work or prompt any accept window...

Comment: If you run from xcode you get any error?

Comment: kind of, Edited question with screenshot

Comment: Did you create your project with sudo command?

Comment: I Did... but removed and added the platform and the message is gone, the problem is that xcode gives me no errors (just warnings in the cordova code), but don't load the emulator. And in the terminal, the error is the same.. any thoughts?

Comment: Create a new project without sudo and check if it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94586/discussion-between-toni-michel-caubet-and-jcesarmobile).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the file permissions using chmod and chown...
It worked in my case

Comment: How do you suggest I should try?

Comment: try this 'sudo chmod 775 /path/to/file'

Comment: If you change folder permissions to the whole folder it should run...I had a small map based application running...
Though it has now stopped running for some reason